# Resizing provoked by QStatusBar::showMessage()

Tags: c++, qt, statusbar

The main window of my application is a QWidget with a QGridLayout comprising several other widgets, including a QStatusBar.

I followed the Qt documentation http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qstatusbar.html, so that my status bar is able to display:

- a "normal message" (namely: "Ready"), by way of adding a QLabel to the status bar using `QStatusBar::addWidget()`.
- temporary messages (that temporarily hide the "normal message"), by calling `QStatusBar::showMessage()`.

My problem is that when a temporary message is shown on or cleared off the status bar, then it apparently triggers `QLayout::activate()` (on the layout of my main window). This in turn possibly provokes a resizing of the other widgets in my window, and I do *not* want that to happen.

The curious (annoying) thing is that the status bar is actually not resized (as it should, it doesn't need to be resized), so I'm not sure why `QStatusBar::showMessage()` would ask the layout to resize anything.

Anyone knows a solution to this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is just a shot in the dark, but statusBar()->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Ignored, QSizePolicy::Fixed);  might keep the status bar from trying to mess with your layout too much.

Comment: I just tried your suggestion, unfortunately it's still the same :(

Comment: If `QLayout::activate()` causes other things to resize in spite of all widget sizes supposedly being the same, there's something horribly wrong. You should be able to call `activate()` on any layout without any effects at all, as many times as you wish - as long as everything is correct. Are you using any custom widgets? Please produce a minimal, self-contained, single-file test case.

Comment: @KubaOber: You're right, there's something unnatural about my layout. It doesn't "naturally" place the widgets where I want them, so I force my widgets to go where I want after any resizing (by doing setGeometry() on the widgets). It's probably a bad way to handle things but I couldn't come up with a better idea. I suppose I should create my own layout class inheriting QLayout, but that sounds like a lot of work. Things is, I'm happy with what I have for the moment, this status bar messages activating the layout are the only thing annoying me. Maybe I'll try to produce a minimal example.

Comment: @Seub The use of a layout and `setGeometry` is exclusive: you can do either one, but never both at the same time. Your code is broken and you must fix it first. "I should create my own layout class inheriting QLayout, but that sounds like a lot of work." The very reason that you've posted this question is that you're making life very hard for yourself already. What you've done so far is a bad hack and I'd never pass it in a code review. It will not work properly, it's not meant to, and you're breaking all sorts of invariants by doing things that way.

Comment: Perhaps you need to tell us how you want to lay out your items, and how do the default layouts come short in this regard. Perhaps it's a simple matter of tweaking some layout settings. Basic `QLayout` implementation is rather simple, there's even an example that comes with Qt. It's *not* a lot of work, not unless the rest of your application is trivial. **TL;DR** You've presupposed a solution without telling us what the problem is. This is a common mistake that I sometimes am guilty of as well, especially in unfamiliar fields.

Answer (score -1):

Use

```
QWidget::adjustSize()
```

To adjust parent widget to fit its content after showing or clearing off the message on the status bar

Comment: the parent widget does not need to be adjusted and I want to prevent it from  doing any resizing.

Comment: By doing so, will not cause child widgets to be resized. Did you even try it at all?

Comment: Ok I just tried, it doesn't work as I expected. My layout resizes the widgets immediately when QStatusBar::showMessage() is called, so no time for QWidget::adjustSize() to prevent it from doing it if I call it after showMessage(). Also, for specific reasons I do not want the main window to adjust the size of its child widgets ever, unless the window is resized itself.